# can I create a dashboard of failed builds in Hudson?

Tags: hudson

I want to create a view of all the (currently) failing builds.  The regex field in view creation only supports the name, not the build status.

I've looked at Radiator but it doesn't work on our (old) Hudson.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [View Job Filter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters), which does provide a filter on Job status:

[image: Job Statuses Filter]

But it remains to be seen if it can be adapted to your (old) Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a radiator, then I think [CI-Eye](https://github.com/netmelody/ci-eye/wiki) will talk to an older Hudson, depending how old it is.

Give it a try and let me know. I'm the project owner, so I can probably fix it for you.

[image: CI-Eye screenshot]